# How does Node-Cron keep track of time after I close the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just installed the npm `node-cron` package. I thought this package just kept track of time when the server was up and running but it looks like I was wrong. I wrote this:

```
cron.schedule("*/30 * * * * *", function() {
    console.log("running a task every 30 secs");
  });
```

However, if I close or restart the server around 20 secs after the console message is displayed, the next message appears after 10 seconds.

I am really happy about this as I thought this was going to be very difficult to do. I am not sure how the server is keeping track of time after I close it. I am using windows. Is this package going to work when I deploy it to Heroku?

Comment: It uses the system clock :) `*/30` means that the task should run when the seconds of the clock are :00 or :30. (But I don’t know what it’ll do on Heroku, or what you need it to do.)

Comment: Oh wow this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you schedule a node-cron with condition, it will set the scheduler to some date and time and will not remove the scheduler on restart or stop of server.

The scheduler will automatically run on that specific date and time.

Here is an article for the same - https://usefulangle.com/post/115/nodejs-cron-job

We can even force the scheduler to not start on restart or stop of server.If the third parameter of scheduler method has been set to false, the cron won't start automatically.